# SQL Join two rows with one

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: Accounts and Transactions. I would like to join them to have an output table as per below:

Accounts Table:

| AccountID | AccounNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Acc1 | 000000001 |
| Acc2 | 000000002 |
| Acc3 | 000000003 |

Transactions Table:

| TransactionID | FromAccount | ToAccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tr1 | Acc1 | Acc2 |
| Tr2 | Acc2 | Acc3 |

Output:

| TransactionID | FromAccount | ToAccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tr1 | 000000001 | 000000002 |
| Tr2 | 000000002 | 000000003 |

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like a simple query with two joins to the same table.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT
t.TransactionID,
A.AccountNumber as FromAccount
A.AccountNumber as ToAccount

FROM Accounts A, Transactions T
WHERE A.AccountNumber = T.FromAccount or A.AccountNumber = T.ToAccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to JOIN with `Accounts` table two times to get your expected result.

The query will be:

```
SELECT TR.TransactionID, 
       A1.AccounNumber AS FromAccount,
       A2.AccounNumber AS ToAccount,
FROM Transactions TR
INNER JOIN Accounts A1 ON A1.AccountID = TR.FromAccount
INNER JOIN Accounts A2 ON A2.AccountID = TR.ToAccount
```